# purrr map instead of apply

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to incorporate more pipes in my code. Oftentimes, I have to break up pipes to use the apply function. Then I found purrr. However, it's not clear to me how exactly it works. Here is what I want, and what I've tried. The main problem is that I want a rowwise computation.

want:

```
apply(mtcars,1,function(x) which.max(x))
```

have:

```
mtcars %>% map_dbl(which.max)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need rowwise, then use `pmap`.  According to `?pmap`

> ... Note that a data frame is a very important special case, in which case pmap() and pwalk() apply the function .f to each row. map_dfr(), pmap_dfr() and map2_dfc(), pmap_dfc() return data frames created by row-binding and column-binding respectively. ...

```
pmap_int(mtcars, ~ which.max(c(...)))
#[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 3
```

---

Also, in `base R`, this can be easily done and efficiently done with `max.col`

```
max.col(mtcars, "first")
#[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 3
```

---

The `map` is used similar to `lapply/sapply` where it loops through each column and apply the function on that column.  So, it would be similar to

```
apply(mtcars, 2, which.max)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect.

Comment: What if I wanted the max (col number) of which element >5 , like this: apply(mtcars,1,max(which(x>5)))

Comment: @chachimouchacha  It would be `pmap_int(mtcars, ~ max(which(c(...) > 5)))`

Comment: Was making up numbers to fit with mtcars, mixed reality with example!